# Rigid body property disappeared from multiple objects all of a sudden

Tags: animation, rigidbody

[image]I was doing a project. Everything was great I setup models, scenes, animation was almost done. I did car physics: wheels, carcass with constraint. Simple stuff. Thing is I did animate this car and rigid body properties did not disappear till at some point I opened blend file and there was none(rigid bodies, rigid bodies constraint objects). After two days I still don't understand how and why they disappeared. What could possibly cause it? I can't recall my exact moves but I did nothing fancy just simple animation and scene setup. Blender version 2.80.53.

Comment: It's called Blender StackExchange, not Dead Meme StackExchange. It would be actually extremely helpful, if you add screenshots of your scene into your question, instead of... whatever this is. Also, be aware that Blender 2.80 is still Beta and still not ready for production stuff.

Comment: Jesus Christ man what's wrong with having some fun. I can add screenshot but I don't think it's gonna help. It is beta but it's like basic stuff and I saw people already using it in production and Andrew Price said it's pretty stable, so I thought why not try. @metaphor_set

Comment: Fun comes at a price, in this case the time of the person who tries to figure out, what you actually mean. (Technical) StackExchange is effective, because we not only keep dead memes out of the way, but also stop people from rambling about their lives, their family, their cats and dogs... Look at other [well-received questions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes) and compare them with yours. They are structured and coherent, have complete information and are generally easy to answer without asking a dozen questions in the comment section.

Comment: Are you serious right now? What are you doing? I can delete "whine about client" and that "i'm not pro.." but everything else is pretty much on point. Listen I understand you, yes question should be short and clear. But this is not the case for a short question. I add little bit about my situation, I didn't ask to explore it.@metaphor_set

Comment: Why, yes, of course I'm dead serious. It's not so much about your content, it's about posting memes instead of meaningful images. And it's also a little bit about the effort people put into their questions (formatting, paragraphs - instead of a wall of text). The more effort you put in, the more likely people will put effort into their answers.

Comment: No. It's not always about effort taking - effort given. It's always about luck. My luck is you. I will edit my question but please stop commenting if you're are not gonna help.

Comment: Can you retrieve data from .blend1 backup file? It is usually saved by default

Comment: Yes, same issue.@Serge L

Comment: As an experiment, just to get the model back and manageable, I'd be making a backup of what you have already and and keep it safe somewhere.  Go back to the other and remove all physics, constraints, animation, shapekeys, whatever, from the model and ONE At A Time, see what brings the mesh back.  It appears on the face of it that  there's interaction between physics and animation, a process that in my (limited) experience can be an unstable mix.  Be mindful that it pays to look for physics strips that hang on in the Dopesheet after removing physics.  Delete them manually if they're there.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'll keep in mind your suggestion. @Edgel3D